# Why is the ternary operator so verbose in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

When I am at the shell, I want to bind my typing to my thoughts, as closely as possible anyways.

I thought the ternary operator would help a lot in this regard, so I resolved to relearn it. But it seem so verbose and redundant!

---

```
ls|% {$_.Attributes  -match "repar" ? "Remove"}
```

The above will fail, because you must include `:`. Where as as with the following,  you can get away with not specifying an `else`:

```
ls|% {if ($_.Attributes  -match "repar"){"Remove"}}
```

---

Even if I were to acquiesce to `ls|% {$_.Attributes  -match "repar" ? "Remove":}`, a still get an error. I must specify a value after `:`

```
ls|% {$_.Attributes  -match "repar" ? "Remove": $null}
```

or just an empty double quote:

```
ls|% {$_.Attributes  -match "repar" ? "Remove": ""}
```

---

```
ls|% {$_.Attributes  -match "repar" ? "Remove": $null}
```

At this point I am wondering, what makes the above superior to the following:

```
ls|% {if ($_.Attributes  -match "repar"){"Remove"}}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How about `ls | ? attributes -match repar | rm -whatif`

Comment: It's not verbose. The issue is that you're trying to force using it when it is not needed.

Comment: The core of the problem is that the expressions you report as failing are not valid ternary expressions. The syntax is `<condition> ? <if-true> : <if-false>`.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_if?view=powershell-7.3#using-the-ternary-operator-syntax

Comment: @js2010 I knew that would do it, but I wanted to put rest to this ternary mess I have been waiding in for weeks, I have now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the English definition of the word ternary:
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ternary

The roots of the word comes from the number three and this matches with the PowerShell ternary operator's usage with its three parts:

```
<condition> ? <if-true> : <if-false>
```

I think your conclusion is 100% accurate. You would not use the ternary operator if you did not have use for all three parts, condition, if-true and if-false.

The ternary operator was introduced in PowerShell version 7 to make if statements with both the true and false conditions easier to express.

Check out this blog article on ideas for when to use the ternary operator:

**PowerShell 7 Ternary Operator: Introduction & Examples**
https://jeffbrown.tech/powershell-7-ternary/

Comment: Thank you for this apt expalantion, I will admit, I should have familarised myself with the english word itself first. Lesson learned.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the IF statement, you just need to wrap the operator in parentheses then $null for the "else":

```
ls | % { ($_.Attributes  -match "repar") ? "Remove" : $null }
```

Edit: Adding this example as i had a hard time figuring out how to run multiple commands together. (Alternatively you could use a script block)

```
ls | % {($_.Attributes -match "repar") ? 
    ((write-host -ForegroundColor Cyan "Remove`t" -NoNewline),("$($_.Name)")) : 
    $null 
    }
```